# checkbox in list using rails will_paginate

Tags: ruby-on-rails, checkbox, will-paginate

I have the list that includes checkbox in each row. All the process are fine in one page. When the records exceeds one page and need to check the record on page 2 or 3, lost the checked value of the previous page. How can I solve this problem. Give me some great ideas.

Answer (score 0):

When you paginate, your page only shows some records and only checkboxes for these records are shown. When you change page, you will show a new set of records, with their own checkboxes (and not the others). Each page is an independent request to the show (or other) method.

What you should do is save the list of checkboxes previously selected, in the controller, pass this list to the new page view, and add them as params in the link to a new page.

I have done it before, but I don’t have the code at hand, but it’s something like this:

Controller

```
def show
  @previous_checks = []
  params[:previous_checks].each do |c|
    @previous_checks << c
  end
  params[:checks].each do |c|
    @previous_checks << c
  end
  #rest of normal code...
end
```

In the view, add checks: @previous_checks in the link to a new page:

```
<%= will_paginate(xxxxxx, :params => { :previous_checks => @previous_checks }) %>
```

In the controller, when you process checks when you submit the form, just use both :checks and :previous_checks.

You probably need some changes in the code to handle the array of previous checks and the params, as some conversion maybe needed

Comment: Your answer is really great. I've tried different ways to get the checked values in controller but I can't. just only get the offset value as the params[:page]. Thanks.

Comment: Can you post the params passed to the controller (from the log), and the final version of the will_paginate command that you put in the view?  Also the html code generated by will_paginate (from your browser developers tools) could help.

Comment: I just only got the params of page when I wrote the will_paginate as your suggestion. The will_paginate format is right because that can pass the params of previous_checks when I assigned the string instead of previous_checks. I traced and found that it is because we can't pass the params[:checks] in controller, so, can't pass the value of previous_checks in view. Does it concern with http methods? I tried my best with your ideas but I couldn't solve it. So,I chose to use other means. Now, my problem is solved but I just want to know the solving method of yours. Thanks for giving your time.